# How to get Zaraz script to load first on webpage?

Tags: javascript, dynatrace, zaraz

I am using Zaraz to load the Dynatrace RUM script on my website. Previously when using just the Dynatrace script it was the first to load in order to make sure the data collected was as accurate as possible. Since trying to use Zaraz to do this the Zaraz script now loads last on the website.

Is there any way to change this so that it also loads first?

I am using Zaraz through Cloudflare and the site is proxied through Cloudflare.